# Copying Cells to a Different Sheet Based off Third Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the bellow code:

```
Private Sub Nonconformance()

Dim cell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
NextFree = Range("'Issues and Actions'!B2:B" & 
Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(sht.Name,"Checklist")>0 Then
        For Each cell In Range("F10:F35")
            If cell.Value = "No" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -5).Copy
                Range("'Issues and Actions'!B" & NextFree).Paste
            ElseIf cell.Value = "Yes" Then
                For Each cell In Range("G10:G35")
                    If cell.Value = "No" Then
                        cell.Offset(-6, 0).Copy
                        Range("'Issues and Actions'!B" & NextFree).Paste
                    End If
                Next cell
        Next cell
    End If
Next sht

End Sub
```

I receive a compile error that says, “For control variable already in use” on line 14. Could someone please provide a solution that will work for this code, or show me a better way to do this? Thanks!

The code is intended to check column F of each worksheet with "checklist" in its name for values of "No", and if column F contains "Yes" then it would also check column G for a value of "No". If any cell in column F or G contained "No" then it would copy the Column A value of the same row with the "No" and paste it to the first blank cell in column B of the sheet named "Issues and Actions".

Comment: you are using `cell` in the two for loop use `cell1` and `cell2` for each for loop

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Cell Value of Matching Row

```vb
Private Sub Nonconformance()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Issues and Actions")
    Dim dfCell As Range:
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, srrg As Range

    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, sws.Name, "Checklist", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set srg = sws.Range("F10:G35")
            For Each srrg In srg.Rows
                If IsNumeric(Application.Match("No", srrg, 0)) Then
                    dfCell.Value = srrg.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value
                    Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(1)
                End If
            Next srrg
        End If
    Next sws
    
    MsgBox "Data nonconformanced.", vbInformation
 
End Sub
```